# Clique number of a graph given its order and average degree

Tags: graphs, clique

> Let $G$ be simple graph of order $N$, and let $\bar{d}$ be its average degree.
>
> 1. Find the maximum value of $\omega(G)$ (the clique number of $G$) as a function of $N$ and $\bar{d}$.
> 2. Find the minimum value of $\omega(G)$ as a function of $n$ and $\bar{d}$.
> 3. What are the minimum and maximum values of $\omega(G)$ when $G$ is $d$-regular?

Comment: This seems like homework.  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I feel like the first part should be a quadratic function(probably). Something like k(k-1)/2 where k is size of maximum clique. I'm not sure how to approach this question when the graph is d-regular though!

Comment: When the graph is $d$-regular, certainly $\omega(G) \leq d+1$, and this is achievable (for example, a clique $K_{d+1}$). Conversely, if $d \leq n$, then you can take the graph on $x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n$ (so $N = 2n$) containing the edges $(x_i,y_{i+j \bmod n})$ for $1 \leq j \leq d$, which is $d$-regular but triangle-free.

Comment: Please edit the question to credit the original source for all copied or quoted material.  Also, you might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Finally, please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, you can post each one separately.